# laravel PresenceChannel joining not working

Tags: laravel, echo, laravel-echo

This is client side js

```
  let user_id = $('meta[name="user-id"]').attr('content');
  let channel = Echo.join('user-' + user_id);
    channel.here((user) => {
      console.log('Here');
      console.log(user);
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        console.log('joining');
        console.log(user);
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        console.log('leaving');
        console.log(user);
    });
```

in laravel echo server shows this error

```
 [11:48:15 AM] - wLO1jq5fW9p_8lOnAAAS left channel: presence-user-1 (transport close)
(node:24532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/laravel-echo-server/dist/channels/presence-channel.js:78:21
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:24532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 18)
[11:48:17 AM] - Preparing authentication request to: http://asapp.buginsoft.kz
[11:48:17 AM] - Sending auth request to: http://asapp.buginsoft.kz/broadcasting/auth

[11:48:17 AM] - W3CiOs736gv0o0OwAAAT authenticated for: presence-user-1
Unable to join channel. Member data for presence channel missing
[11:48:17 AM] - W3CiOs736gv0o0OwAAAT joined channel: presence-user-1
```

This is my MessageSent event

```
public function __construct($message,$id)
{
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('user-'.$this->id);
}
```

This is my console.php

```
Broadcast::channel('user-{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

But my console is clear and not showing logs from joining etc

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your broadcasting callback, you returned a boolean which is asked by private channels. But when you authenticate a presence channel, if the user is allowed, you must return an array of data about this user.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#authorizing-presence-channels